# is normal behaviour in ANNs for the reduction of the loss function to be dependent on the number of neuron in the hidden layer?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm coding my own ANN in python for learning purposes. I've implemented most common optimizations for GD and activations functions and computed numerical gradients to make sure that the gradients calculated by the ANN are correct.

I've tried very simple examples and they work great, most recently however I'm attempting to train a ANN with the MNIST dataset. I started with the first 100 or 1000 images in the dataset just to get a feeling of how many hidden layers and neurons per layer to use. I started for example with a single hidden layer of 16 neurons, and for the mentioned sample works great, the loss function is gradually reduced, however if I used nearly any other number of neuron the loss function changes very little or don't even change during training no matter how many epochs I use. I'm trying suggested topologies that have worked for the whole dataset with similar results.

My reasoning is that maybe there are not enough neurons for the network to work properly but I'm  surprised that multiple cases the loss function doesn't even change, is this normal behaviour or is it more likely that I have some bug in my code?

For what I described I used Adam optimization, leakyReLU as activation function for the hidden layers and softmax for the output layer.

Answer (score 1):

The reduction of loss is not necessarily related to the number of neurons in hidden layer, at least not linearly related after it reaches to some number, and the number is case by case. To understand the relation between the neurons (also the hidden layers) and the loss, you need to understand why we "do" deep or shallow [LINK](https://openreview.net/forum?id=r1Gsk3R9Fm). It is more like the parameterized approximation (such as Least squares method), you only need few necessary parameters to approximate a function. Thus, the 16 neurons in your case is the definition of "few necessary parameters" to solve your problem, more than that numbers may only cause a limited progress in accuracy.
All in all, what ANNs or DL doing is approximation, so the neural size, the network structure or what Optimizer you will chose is highly depending on the data itself, so there are no correct answer in most situations.